# Can we have maximum length of string in API help pages?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, limits

For the type **"string"**, I think there is some upper limit of character count.

For example,

- post title : 200 characters
- post body : 30000 characters

In the help page, currently like this

```
"body": {
    "description": "body of the comment",
    "values": "string",
    "optional": false
}
```

Can we have upper limit also? for example
`"body": {
    "description": "body of the comment",
    "values": "string",
    "max-length": 30000,
    "optional": false
}`

Comment: Strictly speaking, these are limitations on the currently deploy'd SO codebase independent of the API.  There's no min/max length enforced anywhere in that chain.  Not to say we couldn't expose the SO limits... but I'm forced to ask, why would you need this data?  I certainly hope you're not allocating `MAX_STRING_LEN` anywhere...

Comment: @Kevin, There is VARCHAR size in table field settings in my MySQL database, so I am just wondering how to set those.

Comment: @S.Mark - nvarchar(MAX) I suppose.

Comment: @kevin it should probably match the current engine code which is 30000 char body and 150 char title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, here's what we're going to try.

First off, we're **not** giving hard guarantees as to the maximum length of strings returned.  Such a guarantee could create a situation where we might have to release an API revision just to accommodate increased text limits on the trilogy sites, or one - which is equally bad - where the API would return truncated results until the next "natural" revision.

Furthermore, spelling out exact character limits brings us into the realm of Unicode dragons; which, frankly, is [asking alot of developers](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).  This complexity can be seen full force in [Twitter's API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/counting_characters).  People do like to [use](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/44011/zero-width-non-joiner-allows-unclickable-titles) [lots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/32743/how-to-insert-wide-unicode-character-on-stackoverflow) [of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10519/comments-questions-and-answers-dont-trim-unicode-u200b-when-counting-characters) [Unicode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2695/syntax-highlighting-and-non-ascii-characters), so it'd be a more common problem than you might think.

<strike>What we **are** doing is putting our current limits as `suggested_buffer_size` in the documentation.  These are, at best, hints.  Any code you write *must* be able to handle larger data if its returned.  This code will get pushed into production later tonight, in all likelihood.</strike>

Update: The `suggested_buffer_size` limits/properties were removed from the version 2.0+ API. They caused way too many headaches for not enough gain.

Comment: Thank you very much Kevin, `suggested_buffer_size` would be ok.

Comment: Please confirm that `suggested_buffer_size` did not make it into the current version of the API.  If it **did** make it, how do we invoke these help pages?

Comment: @BrockAdams confirmed, those buffer limits are not in version 2.0+; caused way too many headaches for not enough gain.

Answer (score 0):

Well done! now returned JSON on help pages are like this
`...
"title": {
    "description": "title of this post",
    "values": "string",
    "optional": false,
    "suggested_buffer_size": 200
},
"body": {
    "description": "body of this post.",
    "values": "string",
    "optional": true,
    "suggested_buffer_size": 30000
},
...`